# Unable to connect to Django app in Docker container with Nginx

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I cannot connect to my app through the URL which I'm using to create a local certificate when using nginx, mkcert, docker, and django.

I'm trying to deploy a Django app locally with django/cookiecutter on Docker using nginx and mkcert for local certifiactes. This sets up an nginx container using jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine.

I'm able to connect to the app at `127.0.0.1:8000` but now I'm trying to develop locally with HTTPS using `mkcert`. My steps for setting up are as follows:

1. Generate certificates with `mkcert`, in which I set the url as `my-dev-env.local` and the key and cert as `my-dev-env.local.key` and `my-dev-env.local.crt`.
2. Move the key and cert files into the projects `./cert` directory
3. Add the `nginx-proxy` service to my docker-compose file:

```
nginx-proxy:
  image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
  container_name: nginx-proxy
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
  restart: always
  depends_on:
    - django
```

4. Add environment variables in my Django app:

```
# HTTPS
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VIRTUAL_HOST=my-dev-env.local
VIRTUAL_PORT=8000
```

5. Add `"my-dev-env.local"` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in my Django settings.

Everything appears to build and run successfully and as I said, I can connect to the app at `http://localhost:8000/`. When I attempt to reach `https://my-dev-env.local/` I get nowhere:

```
This site can’t be reached
my-dev-env.local’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

I'm confused how my browser is supposed to know to connect to the app when I type in `https://my-dev-env.local/`. Is there something I'm missing in my configuration? Any suggestions for how to debug this issue?

My django container knows the $VIRTUAL_HOST variable but I'm still unsure how my browser, this variable, and nginx are all connected.

Comment: I would be surprised if your browser would know right off the bat. You could try changing `/etc/hosts` file on your computer and appending a local name which browser will then understand. In your case that would be something like `127.0.0.1    my-dev-env.local`. This is of course if you're running Docker on a Mac or Linux computer.

Comment: @MarkoE Thanks for the reply. This was correct and my issue was not fully understanding the template I was working with. Thanks for the help.